# Query limited relations using typeorm(OneToMany) relations?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I use `OneToMany` relations for adding `messages` under `conversations`. Here, I want to query conversation with last messages only.

Here is an example-

```
const conversation = await this.conversationRepository.find({
    where: [
        { user: { id: reqUser.id }, hide_from_user: false },
        { participant: { id: reqUser.id }, hide_from_participant: false }
    ],
    order: {
        updated_at: "DESC"
    },
    relations: {
        user: true,
        participant: true,
        message: true
    }
});
```

It returns all `messages` under particular `conversation`-

[image]

But I need only last `message`. Then how I have to query it? Please help me, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeOrm doesn't support that directly, to do that you have to make another query

```
      import { InjectRepository } from "typeorm";

      const conversation = await this.conversationRepository.find({
    where: [
        { user: { id: reqUser.id }, hide_from_user: false },
        { participant: { id: reqUser.id }, hide_from_participant: false }
    ],
    order: {
        updated_at: "DESC"
    },
    relations: {
        user: true,
        participant: true,
    }
});

    conversation.messages = await InjectRepository(Message)
    .createQueryBuilder('message')
    .where('message.conversation = :id' , {conversation.id});
    .limit(1)  
    .orderBy('message.id', 'Desc')
    .getMany()
```

Comment: Where I found `getRepository`? I am using nestjs.

Comment: I am only getting type errors. Please see my updated questions.

Comment: Answer Updated,  `import { getRepository } from "typeorm";`

Comment: @Savana did you get the result you want?

Comment: Yes, I found my solve. `getRepository` is deprecated. I use nestjs `InjectRepository` here

Comment: Ah yes for the last version of typeorm, I'll update my answer, thanks for your sharing